# Correlation of randomly oriented unit vectors

Tags: correlation

Let $R(\alpha):u\rightarrow v$ be a random transformation from Euclician 3D unit vector $u$ to same such unit vector $v$ so that $\measuredangle (u,v) \le \alpha$. The probability density is constant within $\alpha$. My question is, how to estimate such $n$ so that $R^n(u)$ is reasonably uncorrelated with $u$? Rough lower estimate would be $n \approx \pi/\ \alpha $ but I'd love to have more solid ground for such estimate.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "uncorrelated"?  My concern is that every rotation has an axis and that no matter how many times you apply the rotation, unit vectors near that axis will barely change, so there won't be any eventual reduction to zero correlation.

Comment: I am no mathematician, but I mean uncorrelated - as in, if I provide you with R^n(u), you would not be able to determine vector u with better accuracy than guessing. The function R is applied successive, iterative way and no unit vector of the sphere is invariant to it.

Comment: My meaning is the same: if you provide me with $R^n(u)$ and this is close to the axis of $R,$ then $R^n(u)$ will be close to $u:$ that's "correlation" in the sense you describe.  I wonder whether by "$R^n(u)$" you might mean choosing $n$ independent random rotations and applying them in succession?  That is *very* different than what $R^n$ means, which is to obtain a *single* random rotation $R$ and apply it $n$ times.

Comment: You are perfectly right. Dayne made a good answer for a single rotation in range ($-\alpha, \alpha$) which was not what I meant. I could have been more clear in my question. What I had in mind is essentially random walker on a sphere where each random step taken is within some given alpha. As for correlation, it was my assumption that if I take randomly two unit vectors, it is expected them to be mutually orthogonal. In any case, would you recommend me to try fix the question or try asking whole new question?

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful comments.  Because you already have an upvoted answer to an interpretation of your question, it's probably better to start a new thread with a clarification of your intended question.  I suggest also clarifying what you mean by the "probability density is constant within $\alpha,$" because that has several natural interpretations in this context. For instance, it could mean the amount of rotation has a uniform distribution but the rotation axis is random; or it could mean you want to select uniformly from all rotations of less than $\alpha;$ or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, $R(\alpha):u \to v$ is a rotation by amount $\theta$ such that
\begin{align}
\theta \sim U[-\alpha,\alpha] \\
\lambda \equiv \frac{\theta+\alpha}{2\alpha} \sim U[0,1]
\end{align}

(I am taking distribution from $-\alpha$ because otherwise the rotation is happening only in one direction and the correlation will become cyclical).

Let $\theta_i$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$ be $n$ rotations, and $\theta_{(n)} \equiv \sum_1^n \theta_i$ be the final angle between $u,v$ after $n$ rotations.

Define

$$\lambda_n = \frac{\theta_{(n)} + n\alpha}{2\alpha} = \sum\limits_1^n \frac{\theta+\alpha}{2\alpha}$$

So, $\lambda_n$ follows the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), with parameter $n$.

Now we also need to define what is a reasonable range of correlation to claim that $u,v$ are uncorrelated. For reasonably high number of dimensions, this can come from theory (from distribution of the correlation coefficient). However, here since it's just a three-dimensional space, we should define it.

Say, we consider $(-0.2,0.2)$ as this range. Also note that (pearson) correlation is just $\cos \theta_{(n)}$.

Therefore,

\begin{align}
-0.2 &\leq\cos\theta_{(n)} \leq 0.2 \\
\cos^{-1}(0.2) &\leq \theta_{(n)} \leq \cos^{-1} (-0.2) \\
1.37 &\leq \theta_{(n)} \leq 1.77
\end{align}

For this range of $\theta_{(n)}$, we can get a range of $\lambda_n$:

$$\Lambda:=\bigg( \frac{1.37+n\alpha}{2\alpha},\frac{1.77+n\alpha}{2\alpha}\bigg)$$

From the distribution, we can get:$\mathbb P(\lambda_n \in\Lambda)$ as a function of $n$. Finally, MLE can be used to estimate $n$ to maximize this probability.

Comment: How do you obtain $\cos(\theta_{(n)})$ as the correlation?  Indeed, what exactly do you mean by using a single value to characterize the correlation between unit *vectors*?  Doesn't that need a correlation matrix?

Comment: @whuber: I understand that taking unit vectors of just 3 dimension as samples of a single random variable (as opposed to considering them as random vectors) doesn't make much sense but I thought that was OP's requirement.

Comment: @Dayne thank you for your effort to answer my question. As far as I can see it, you made a good answer but not to the question I had in mind - that was my fault, I could and should have been more clear. I am not a mathematician and didn't know that I need a matrix to characterize relation of two random vectors. Intuitively, I figured if I pick randomly two vectors from unit sphere, they would be orthogonal and didn't google it beyond that. I'll try reformulating question.

Comment: StipeGalić: No issues. I just read the comments by @whuber on the question and I realized that I wrongly assumed that the rotation is happening in the same plane (i.e., there is no change in axis of rotation). This is clearly very restrictive. Please ignore my answer. I should perhaps consider deleting it.